# Grails + Shiro + LDAP

Tags: grails, groovy, ldap, shiro

I am searching for a good tutorial to configure Grails + Shiro + LDAP.
I have already spent almost a week but no luck yet.

I have used the command grails `shiro-quick-start` to create all the files.
But I have no idea how to configure LDAP with shiro.

Could you please give me some clue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an LDAP realm I'll come back with a more full answer, but look at this http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Shiro-plugin-and-LDAP-td1392857.html for a start.

basically create the realm `grails create-ldap-realm`

then add the ldap config top config.groovy

Comment: OK it looks like the script to create the LDAP realm isn't currently working.